# Flutter existSync doesn't find temporary file

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get a temporary office file from the file system on Mac but on some occasions when I call file.existSync() it says that the file doesn't exist. The thing I don't understand is it's inconsistent. In macos some temporary lock files just have ~$ added to the front whereas others (I think with longer names) have the same but the first two characters from the filename are removed (e.g filename.docx would be ~$lename.docx)

```
  // Example filename
   ~$sting really long filename that will be over a certain number of characters.docx

final lockFileName = "\~\$${fileName.substring(2)}";
  final lockWithFirstTwoCharsRemoved = File("${dir.path}/$lockFileName");
  if (lockWithFirstTwoCharsRemoved.existsSync()) {
```

The above existsSync fails but only sometimes

[image: here is the temporary file]

Comment: Are you certain that the file exists at the time your code is executed?

Comment: @jamesdlin I am calling  (await launchUrl(url)) just before it but I guess could be possible that the existsSync() is being called before the file is launched?

Comment: What URL?  How is that related to the lock file?

Comment: @jamesdlin the url is the file path of a file loaded from the server and saved in a temporary directory. I'm first opening the file then trying to create a watcher on the temporary file that word creates on opening of the file

Comment: @jamesdlin the only way I can think to solve is it to put a timer in place before calling existsSync() to make sure the file has definitely opened but must be a better way to solve it

Comment: The `Future` from `launchUrl` completes when the URL was launched.  What the launched application (in this case, Word) does afterward is its own business; `launchUrl`'s job is done.  Therefore you should not expect that Word's (possibly asynchronous) machinery to open a file (and to create a temporary file as a byproduct) finishes before `launchUrl`'s `Future` completes.

Comment: that makes sense. Much appreciated @jamesdlin